# I am trying to get user input until user enter 0 and then show maximum value among them in JAVA

Tags: java, loops

I am a beginner to java and don't know to write a program using loops that prompt the user to enter a number till user does does not enter 0.
When user enter 0 then system should display MAX number among user input

QUE 2
 Write a program to ask the user to enter a sequence of numbers (double type). The numbers are separated by the return key (and give a prompt for each enter). The user ends the sequence by entering a 0. Then output the maximum number of all the entered numbers. Here is an example (the part in italic is the user’s input):  Please enter a sequence of numbers, separated by return, and then end this sequence with a 0 at last: 25 
Next number: 35.6
Next number: 112.112 
Next number: 0 
The maximum among your enters is 112.112

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Q3

 {
 public static void main(String[] args[])
   {
    double n;
   // double i;
    double MAX=0;

    System.out.println("Please Enter the number: ");
    Scanner Kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = Kb.nextDouble();
   if(n>0){
     System.out.println("Please Enter the number: ");
         n = Kb.nextDouble();
         return;

}
    else if(n==0) {
    if (MAX>0){
        MAX=n;
        return ;

    }

  }  
 return;
}

 }
```

Comment: copy the code in the post rather screenshot it.

Comment: post in your question not in comment.

Comment: can you code it I tried my best but code not solve

Comment: not working please can you code it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Collections.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) ,

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
  System.out.println("enter a number :");
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    
   while (kb.hasNext() ) {
            double input = kb.nextDouble();
            if(input == 0){
                break;
            }
            doubleList.add(input);
        }

 System.out.println("Max Value Entered : " + Collections.max(doubleList));
```

Comment: Please do it just using loops. I am yet a begginer

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of the max and each time a user inputs a number check if it is greater than that max

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3 {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        double max = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number: ");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number = kb.nextDouble();

        while (number != 0) {
            if (max < number) {
                max = number;
            }
            number = kb.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("The max is " + max);
    }
}
```

Since zero is the terminal character then negative input can be essentially ignored and the initial value of max as zero is acceptable.

Note that nextDouble can throw an `InputMismatchException` if the user decides to give you input that can not be parsed to a double.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double max = 0;
while(true){
    double number = sc.nextDouble();
    if(max<number){
        max = number;
    }
    else if(number==0){
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print(max);
```